# Encrypting pass in javascript with a key, then retrieve the original password (as securely as possible)

Tags: javascript, sqlite, passwords, encryption

I would like to encrypt and save a user password in a database, all this with javascript, and later decrypt it. I would like to use a key to encrypt/decrypt all passwords. I was thinking about storing them in an sqlite database.

Do you think this way the database will be secure in case of theft? I guess it will highly depend on the algorithm and implementation.

Can you point me in the right direction to any library that has this functionality, allows me to encrypt/decrypt?

Can you recommend me a library to handle sqlite db. with javscript?

I would normally do all this with some webscripting language without decrypting the pass, but I need to do this with js. and I am fairly new to the language. So any advices would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the encryption/decryption to happen on the client side? This would be very insecure. Why do you need the decryption anyway? Usually you only calculate a hash and only compare the hashes, and this calculation has to take place on the server side.

Comment: Yes I know this should happen on the server side and that is why I said that normally I would do this with some webscripting language. What I want to do is a firefox add-on that saves passwords to sites and can log automatically in those sites by just clicking a button. In order to do that I need to save them locally somehow. If there is a better way to do this let me know please!

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel? Firefoy already knows how to remember passwords of web sides.

Comment: Yes, I know. It is a great choice indeed. But I wanted my add-on to do something more actually. Anyway I am reinventing the wheel a little and I think I will be better off using firefox password management.

Answer (score 0):

Client side code should not be used for securing a connection, as the Javascript code itself was loaded from the insecure connection and is thus prone to tampering.

Just load your script and do all sensitive communication through https and and you should be fine.

Comment: In this case I will be loading the javascript code in the client side from the client side, I think, since it is a firefox add-on. The add-on will just autcomplete a form with predefined choices and I would like to retrieve the pass from a db.

Comment: @eter: Doesn't Firefox already have password management stuff included? Are you sure you can't leverage that instead?

Comment: You are right, it has. The thing is that I wanted my add-on to just click a button, open a bunch of sites in a row and log in them. Firefox pass management just autofill those fields. In any case I guess using it will be safer than implementing a new one. But imagine some manages to attack firefox, wouldn't be logical to look for pass management db and steal it instead of a more unkown add-on. I know, I know security through obscurity...

Answer (score 0):

If you encrypting/decrypting anything, it should be done on the server.

A hacker can view the source code of the JS to figure out the hashing algorithm, and assuming they're using a packet sniffer or similar piece of software, compare that algorithm to the data sent by the user.

For what you want to achieve, you could connect to the server with HTTPS, and send passwords and receive authentication notices to/from the server via `xmlhttprequest`.

I do not know of any algorithms for doing everything on the client, probably for the reasons listed above. There are plenty of PHP hashing algorithms however. This site may be of use: http://phpsec.org/

---

Edit: (Read your comment on the OP) Doesn't Firefox offer this functionality already? In any  case, saving passwords made on the local machine can be stored on the local machine. When a page is revisited, you could auto-fill the related password fields. The only security threat there is if the host computer is compromised. I don't know any code samples for this though.